# How to draw a line in google combo chart

Tags: bar-chart, google-visualization

I am new to google chart. I want to draw a red line as shown in following image.
Please help me how to do that.[image]

I have show my requirement line in above image.
how to do it? please help me. I used Combo Chart.
My code as follows.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [ 'Time', 'Col1',{ role: 'style' }, 'col2'],
            [ '09:50', 1000,'color: #B0C4DE', null],
            [ '10:00', 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA',1400],
            [ '10:30', 1500, 'color: #EEE8AA',1400],
            [ '11:00', 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE',null],
            [ '11:30', 1200, 'color: #B0C4DE',null],
            [ '12:00', 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE',null],
            [ '12:30', 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA',1200],
            [ '01:00', 1300, 'color: #EEE8AA',1200],
            [ '01:30', 1600, 'color: #B0C4DE',null]]);

    var options = {
        width : 1001,
        height : 500,
        vAxis : {
            format : '#[kw]',
            viewWindowMode:'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
                max:3000,
                min:0
            },
            ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 3000]
        },

        seriesType : "bars",
        series : {
            1 : {
                type : "line"
            }
        },
        legend : {
            position : 'none'
        },
        colors : ['#ff0000','#008000']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document
            .getElementById('number_format_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the right idea with the *green* line already,
here are a couple options for the *red* line...

in order to get the rise in the line,
a new row must be added between the two points.

1. **Discrete Axis** (`'string'` values) --
   if the middle portion of the *red* line needs to be vertical,
   then a discrete axis will not work.
   because the hAxis ticks cannot be set,
   and there will be a gap for each row,
   forcing the line to be diagonal.
2. **Continuous Axis** (`'timeofday'` values) --
   the middle portion of the *red* line can be vertical,
   because the hAxis ticks can be set and do not repeat.
   however, a `ColumnChart` with a Continuous axis, is more difficult to format (imo).

see following, working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var seriesOptions = {
      type : "line"
    };

    new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div0')).
    draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [ 'Time', 'Col1', { role: 'style' }, 'Col2', 'Col3'],
        [ '09:50', 1000, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ '10:00', 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1600],
        [ null, null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1600],
        [ null, null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1700],
        [ '10:30', 1500, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1700],
        [ '11:00', 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ '11:30', 1200, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ '12:00', 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ '12:30', 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1400],
        [ null, null, 'color: #B0C4DE', 1200, 1400],
        [ null, null, 'color: #B0C4DE', 1200, 1500],
        [ '01:00', 1300, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1500],
        [ '01:30', 1600, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null]
      ]),
      {
        width : 1001,
        height : 500,
        vAxis : {
          format : '#[kw]',
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow: {
            max:3000,
            min:0
          },
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 3000]
        },
        seriesType : "bars",
        series : {
          1 : seriesOptions,
          2 : seriesOptions
        },
        legend : {
          position : 'none'
        },
        colors : ['transparent', '#008000', '#ff0000']
      }
    );

    new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1')).
    draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [ 'Time', 'Col1', { role: 'style' }, 'Col2', 'Col3'],
        [ [09,50,00], 1000, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ [10,00,00], 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1600],
        [ [10,15,00], null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1600],
        [ [10,15,00], null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1700],
        [ [10,30,00], 1500, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1400, 1700],
        [ [11,00,00], 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ [11,30,00], 1200, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ [12,00,00], 1300, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null],
        [ [12,30,00], 1200, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1400],
        [ [12,45,00], null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1400],
        [ [12,45,00], null, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1500],
        [ [13,00,00], 1300, 'color: #EEE8AA', 1200, 1500],
        [ [13,30,00], 1600, 'color: #B0C4DE', null, null]
      ]),
      {
        bar: {
          gap: 10
        },
        width : 1001,
        height : 500,
        hAxis : {
          ticks: [[09,30,00], [09,50,00], [10,00,00], [10,30,00], [11,00,00], [11,30,00], [12,00,00], [12,30,00], [13,00,00], [13,30,00], [14,00,00]]
        },
        vAxis : {
          format : '#[kw]',
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow: {
            max:3000,
            min:0
          },
          ticks: [0, 1000, 2000, 3000]
        },
        seriesType : "bars",
        series : {
          1 : seriesOptions,
          2 : seriesOptions
        },
        legend : {
          position : 'none'
        },
        colors : ['transparent', '#008000', '#ff0000']
      }
    );
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Discrete Axis</div>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
<div>Continuous Axis</div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```